# Rails4 - Supress view comments to be published in the web pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, embedded-ruby

Is there any way to suppress the comments in the views to get published in the webpages?

--Update--
I have lots of comments and commented lines in my views as shown below

```
  <!--  <div class="col-md-3">-->
      <!--<span class="user"><%= link_to micropost.user.name, micropost.user %></span>-->
  <!--<%= link_to micropost.user.name, micropost.user %>-->
  <!--  </div>-->
  <!--</div>-->
```

Comment: We'd need a bit more information than just a sentence. Do you have any code to show what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: @User089247 Sorry for not providing the code. Added code. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use erb comments:

```
<%#  <div class="col-md-3"> %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using c9.io and i usually select the code and ask the GUI to comment to code which adds the comments as above. Thanks for the information